# AJAX is working on one computer but not another

Tags: ajax

Ok, I'm working on a golf club site and when you change the condition of the club, it should change the price with AJAX.  It works on my computer and version of Firefox (14.0.1) but it just changes the price to $0.00 on my brother's computer and version of Firefox (14.0.1).  Once it changes it to $0.00, it won't change anymore on his computer.  We've only had this problem on Firefox.  Does anyone have any idea why this would do this?

I was thinking it might have something to do with XMLHttpRequest() but it doesn't make sense that it would work on one computer and not another when it's the same version of the browser.

Here's the Javascript file.

```
var xmlHttp

function GetXmlHttpObject()
{
var xmlHttp=null;
try
  {
  // Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
  xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
catch (e)
  {
  // Internet Explorer
  try
    {
    xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    }
  catch (e)
    {
    xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
  }
return xmlHttp;
}

function quantityPrice(ClubType, Make, Model, ShaftType, Condition, Qty)
{ 
xmlHttp=GetXmlHttpObject();
if (xmlHttp==null)
  {
  alert ("Sorry, your browser does not support this website. Your browser needs to be upgraded to newer version.");
  return;
  } 
var url="includes/getPriceViaQuantity.php";
url=url+"?ClubType="+ClubType;
url=url+"&Make="+Make;
url=url+"&Model="+Model;
url=url+"&ShaftType="+ShaftType;
url=url+"&Condition="+Condition;
url=url+"&Qty="+Qty;
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=quantityChangePrice;
xmlHttp.open("GET",url,true);
xmlHttp.send(null);
}


function quantityChangePrice() 
{ 
if (xmlHttp.readyState==4)
{ 
document.getElementById("quote").innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText;

}
}

function ironsetPrice(ClubType, Make, Model, ShaftType, Condition, Qty, MakeUp)
{ 
xmlHttp=GetXmlHttpObject();
if (xmlHttp==null)
  {
  alert ("Sorry, your browser does not support this website. Your browser needs to be upgraded to newer version.");
  return;
  } 
var url="includes/getPriceViaMakeUp.php";
url=url+"?ClubType="+ClubType;
url=url+"&Make="+Make;
url=url+"&Model="+Model;
url=url+"&ShaftType="+ShaftType;
url=url+"&Condition="+Condition;
url=url+"&Qty="+Qty;
url=url+"&MakeUp="+MakeUp;
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=ironsetChangePrice;
xmlHttp.open("GET",url,true);
xmlHttp.send(null);
}


function ironsetChangePrice() 
{ 
if (xmlHttp.readyState==4)
{ 
document.getElementById("quote").innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText;

}
}
```

Comment: Suggestions? Yes: post your code.

Comment: The suggestion is to download FireBug and look at the console output to see what errors might be lurking in there. It will give you some insight into what might be different.